# OR equality constraint for binary integer program

Tags: propositional-calculus, linear-programming, boolean-algebra, integer-programming, binary-programming

I am trying to find a way to implement an OR equality constraint in a Binary Integer Program.  For example, say I want to add the following logical condition to the program:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 1\; \text{OR}\;  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 3$$

$$\textbf{x}\in \mathbb{B}^5$$

The big-M method does not seem to work here because we are dealing with equalities rather than inequalities.  I also have not seen any literature on this after a search.  My only idea is to come up with all the possible partitions of the five variables and individually assign constraints as according.  For example...

$$\text{IF } x_1 \geq 1 \rightarrow x_{2,...,5} \leq 0 \text{ OR } x_1 \geq 1 \rightarrow x_2 \geq1, x_3 \geq 1, x_4 \leq 0, x_5 \leq 0 \text{ OR } ...$$

And then use the big-M method.  But this is obviously very tedious and the constraints grow exponentially for such a simple OR statement.  Do you have any ideas/hints on how to approach this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting two more binary variables $y_1,y_2$ in a way:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=y_1+3y_2$$
where
$$y_1+y_2=1$$

Comment: That is much more simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one additional binary variable $y$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i = 1 + 2y.$$